# SQL Server: Cannot find data type date and unable to set compatibility

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a install script that uses DATE.  I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2, and it doesn't like the date type.

```
Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot find data type date.
```

So I tried setting the compatibility of the database to 100 using the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE znode_multifront SET COMPATIBILITY = 100
```

I receive the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '100'.
```

So I tried going into SQLCMD mode and used the following:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel znode_multifront, 100;
```

Which produced the following error:

```
Msg 15416, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dbcmptlevel, Line 70
Usage: sp_dbcmptlevel [dbname [, compatibilitylevel]]
```

I am very new to SQL Server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alter database znode_multifront
set compatibility_level = 100
go
```

You were close.  The set option is `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL`, not `COMPATIBILITY` like you have in your original post.

You will need `ALTER` permission on the database to execute the above query.

Comment: @user1132388 Are you sure you have SQL Server 2008?  Run this to ensure your version: `select @@version`

Comment: "Why do I need to query, when it says right there.." Oh. Yes, it was 2005. It's SSMS that's 2008.  Thanks so much for your help.