# SQL Server : Can not find datatype numeric(2,0)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

When I try to create a table containing a column with the datatype `numeric(2,0)`, I get an error

> Msg 2715
>   Can not find datatype numeric(2,0)

What is the problem with that datatype ?

Comment: alter database  database_name
set compatibility_level = 100
go

Comment: Please mention you server version and details. it seems to be compatibility issue, if so please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744455/sql-server-cannot-find-data-type-date-and-unable-to-set-compatibility